# Apply a function to each row of a Dataset

Tags: dataset, associations

Have a `Dataset` which is derived from the output from another program.
Have written some functions to retrieve and format this data.
Can make this work as intended by using `Table` to apply the function to each row of the `Dataset`.
But cannot achieve the same result when attempting to use some of the built in capabilities of `Dataset`.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Below is the statement that works with `Table` but doesn't work with the alternate syntax.
Both lines are intended to apply the function `dsGetValueList` to each row of `dsApples`.

> ```
> dsAllAppleParamValues = Table[dsGetValueList[dsAllApples[i], dsApplesAllParams],
>                               {i, 1, Length@dsAllApples}]; 
>
> dsAllAppleParamValues2 =
> dsAllApples[All, dsGetValueList[#, dsApplesAllParams] &] // Normal;
> ```

The structure of the `Dataset` might be non-standard, but it is derived from another program and that can't be changed.  Further background: the source file is a JSON file and that can be `Import`-ed with the option `"RawJSON"` to obtain a `Dataset`.

Code for a test case below. In summary the code changes data like this:

[image: Dataset content]

to this:

[image: Results after processing]

```
(*sample data*)
item01 = <| "name" -> "item01", "class" -> "apples" , 
  "params" -> {<| "name" -> "TYPE", "value" -> "fuji"|>
    , <| "name" -> "WEIGHT", "value" -> "0.5"|>
    , <| "name" -> "COLOR", "value" -> "red"|>
     }|>
item02 = <| "name" -> "item02", "class" -> "apples" , 
   "params" -> {<| "name" -> "TYPE", "value" -> "gala"|>
     , <| "name" -> "COLOR", "value" -> "red"|>
     , <| "name" -> "EXP_DATE", "value" -> "10/10/20"|>
     , <| "name" -> "WEIGHT", "value" -> "1.5"|>
      }|>;
item03 = <| "name" -> "item03", "class" -> "apples" , 
   "params" -> {<| "name" -> "TYPE", "value" -> "granny"|>
     , <| "name" -> "COLOR", "value" -> "green"|>
      }|>;
item04 =  <| "name" -> "item04", "class" -> "oranges" , 
   "params" -> {<| "name" -> "TYPE", "value" -> "navwl"|>
     , <| "name" -> "WEIGHT", "value" -> "3.5"|>
     , <| "name" -> "EXP_DATE", "value" -> "09/10/20"|>
      }|>;
item05 =  <| "name" -> "item05", "class" -> "oranges" , 
   "params" -> {<| "name" -> "TYPE", "value" -> "seville"|>
     , <| "name" -> "WEIGHT", "value" -> "1.5"|>
     , <| "name" -> "EXP_DATE", "value" -> "09/10/20"|>
      }|>;
dsAll = Dataset[{item01, item02, item03, item04, item05}];

(*useful functions*)
dsGetName[ds_] := ds["name"]
dsGetValue[ds_, pName_] :=  Module[{paramDS, valueList},
  paramDS =  ds["params"] ;
  valueList = Normal@paramDS[Select[#name == pName &] , "value"];
  If[Length[valueList] > 0, First[valueList], "-"]
  ]
dsGetValueList[ds_, pList_List] := 
 Module[{}, dsGetValue[ds, #] & /@ pList]

(*retrieve metadata about apples: their names and parameters*)
dsAllApples =  dsAll[Select[#class == "apples" &] ]
dsAllAppleNames = dsAllApples[All, dsGetName]  // Normal;
dsApplesAllParams = 
  dsAllApples[All, "params", All, "name"] // Normal // Flatten // 
   Union;
(*retrieve parameter values for each apple, there may be missing values*)
(**-- the first statement works as intended*)
(* -- second statement does not*)
dsAllAppleParamValues = 
  Table[dsGetValueList[dsAllApples[i], dsApplesAllParams], {i, 1, 
    Length@dsAllApples}];
dsAllAppleParamValues2 = 
  dsAllApples[All, dsGetValueList[#, dsApplesAllParams] &] // Normal;
Equal[dsAllAppleParamValues2, dsAllAppleParamValues]
(*format results*)
r1 = Prepend[Transpose[dsAllAppleParamValues], dsAllAppleNames] // 
   Transpose ;
TableForm[r1, 
 TableHeadings -> {None, Prepend[dsApplesAllParams, "Name"]}]
```

Comment: Try `dsAllAppleParamValues2 = 
 dsAllApples[All, dsGetValueList[Dataset@#, dsApplesAllParams] &] // 
  Normal`

Comment: nice!  that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between your two approaches is that in the first version, extracting parts of a dataset returns the part wrapped in [`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset) while using the second approach, the part is not wrapped in [`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset). So, you can just add the [`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset) wrapper yourself with:

```
dsAllAppleParamValues2 = dsAllApples[
    All,
    dsGetValueList[Dataset@#, dsApplesAllParams]&
] //Normal;

dsAllAppleParamValues == dsAllAppleParamValues2
```

> True

That being said, the version without the [`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset) head is probably easier to work with, so I would modify your dsGetValueList function to work with non-[`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset) objects (in this case, just an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association)).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way that generates the columns in the order that they occur in the original dataset:

```
dsAll[
  Select[#class==="apples"&] /* KeyUnion
, <| "Name" -> #name, #name -> #value& /@ #params |>&
]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

If the exact order of the columns is important, an additional re-ordering stage can be added:

```
dsAll[
  Select[#class==="apples"&] /* KeyUnion
, <| "Name" -> #name, #name -> #value& /@ #params |>&
][All, {"Name", "COLOR", "EXP_DATE", "TYPE", "WEIGHT"}]
```

[image: dataset screenshot, columns reordered]

Comment: Thanks!  That is an efficient way to get to the desired end state.  Very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

This is quite a bit awkward, but perhaps you can use this as a starting point:

```
dsApples = dsAll[Select[#class === "apples" &], {"name", "params"}];

tmp = Join[dsApples[All, Key["name"] /* <|"Name" -> Identity|>], 
           Dataset[KeyUnion[(Apply[AssociationThread] @* Transpose) /@ 
                            Normal[dsApples[All, Lookup["params"] /* Values]],
                            Missing[] &]], 2];

tmp[All, {"Name", "COLOR", "EXP_DATE", "TYPE", "WEIGHT"}]
```

[image: new Dataset]

I'll leave the reformatting to a `TableForm[]` object up to you.